# how to darken an svg that is being used for a cursor

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, custom-cursor

This is the code of the svg I am using in scss as a cursor. It is a crosshair of vertical and horizontal lines, and they are currently opaque and barely visible. I need to get them to black with no opacity, but nothing I have changed in the code works. I am working in ReactJS using SASS css: `cursor: url(crosshairs.svg), auto;`.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/)  EDIT: was height: 3301, width:2161 reduced to x128 else it wont show up-->

<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="128"
   height="128"
   viewBox="0 0 873.389 571.765"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg8"
   inkscape:version="0.92.3 (unknown)"
   sodipodi:docname="fullscreen-crosshair-1650x1080.svg">
  <defs
     id="defs2" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="0.25"
     inkscape:cx="1437.71"
     inkscape:cy="1122.57"
     inkscape:document-units="mm"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     showgrid="false"
     units="px"
     inkscape:window-width="1680"
     inkscape:window-height="1016"
     inkscape:window-x="0"
     inkscape:window-y="0"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata5">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1"
     transform="translate(0,274.765)">
    <path
       style="fill:none;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.793751;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
       d="M 436.694,-322.259 V 344.493"
       id="path10"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
    <path
       style="fill:none;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.793751;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none"
       d="M -58.6065,11.1175 H 931.996"
       id="path12"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: @RobertLongson spot on, sir. that did it. I could have sworn I tried it already but maybe only increased it to 1, 10 did the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increase the stroke-width of the paths. stroke-width:10 seems pretty opaque to me for instance.